# Can I use a font for English text, and another font for Arabic/Persian text?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code, arabic, persian

Since there's no free font which supports both scripts, I need to use different fonts for different scripts. Is there any setting to differentiate English and non-English texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a "free" monospaced font that includes both Persian/Arabic and Latin scripts. Meet [Vazir Code](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-code-font)

Answer (score 4):

in **Setting.json** , in **"Editor.fontFamily"** just add fonts that you want

for example if you want a font for English and another one for persian you go like this :

```
"Editor.fontFamily" : "EnglishFont, PersianFont"
```

Comment: `"editor.fontFamily": "'Vazirmatn', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace"`

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a web project, you can just put both fonts in your font stack:

`font-family: EnglishFont, ArabicPersianFont, sans-serif;`

When an Arabic character is not present in the English font, your browser will move on to the next font, in this case your Arabic/Persian font.

If your English font *does* contain (some) Arabic characters, the browser will use those. If this is undesired, you can either subset the font to contain only Latin characters, or you can use a Unicode range in your `@font-face` declaration to tell it to only use it for Latin characters. It will then move on to the next font for Arabic characters, even if they're in your English font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: EnglishFont;
  src: url('...');
  unicode-range: U+0020-024F; /* Only Latin */
}
```

Comment: I want to use the exact same thing in vs code. @RoelN

Comment: @Nitwit Sure, go ahead. The concept is the same.